# Styling scrollbar for iOS safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `::-webkit-scrollbar`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`, and `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` to style a scrollbar in a DIV, and it's working perfectly.

But while I was testing it on iOS safari, I noticed that the scrolling isn't smooth (doesn't use "Momentum Scrolling"). I could fix it by using the following css on it:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

That made the scrolling smooth, but the styling is gone.

So my question: is there any way to keep the scrollbar smooth on iOS devices while the scrollbar styling is taking effect?